# How to display "Whatsapp like" Android notifications

Tags: android, push-notification

[image: Whatsapp notification with user icon]

I can't find the way to display push notifications with user icon, as Whatsapp and Telegram do...

Tried with

```
.setLargeIcon(myLargeIcon)
```

but it's a different layout.
Tried also with similar questions on StackOverflow but without success.

Comment: You can always make a totally cusotm layout:  https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/custom-notification

Comment: Did you read the [guide to showing a conversation in a notification](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/expanded#message-style)? That's what they use.

Comment: Did try custom layout but app's icon is always separated and it's not overlayed on the user's icon.
Did try conversations but it's a different layout.

Comment: Found this Kotlin code 
https://github.com/android/user-interface-samples/tree/main/People
It shows the notification as I need. 
So I translated Kotlin code to Java, but does not show the notification as I need.
Maybe a library version issue?